# Android - Application closes on pressing power button

Tags: android

I have made an application named TicTacToe having AI. The problem is when I press my phone's power button and press it again to start my phone - what i notice is my app is closed and I see the home screen. I want my app to still run even after pressing the power button. ThankYou in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

I think the app is minimized. Long press the home button the app is shown then click the app it will resume.

Comment: the App developer configure this kind of process.So we can't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If by power button you do not mean turning the phone off, you can simply make use of the `onresume` and `onpause` functions. More detail on this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

If this is not working for you, try to log the runtime errors that the app gives and see if there are bugs in the code.

Comment: Thank you, there are no bugs and i have checked log!! I will try those!